# Singular and plural usage of "premise"

Tags: plural-forms

Which one of these sentences is correct? Is it:

> One of the premises.

Or

> One of the premise.

Thank you.

Comment: Please say whether YOU think it should be "premise" or "premises". And if you want us to choose between two sentences, please supply two sentences.

Comment: If you could include more context for these sentences, that would be appreciated. There are two possible definitions for this word.

Answer (score 3):

The structure `one of the` is always followed by the plural nouns. Because you are *selecting* one from two/three/many. Said that...

> One of the ***premises***...

is correct. I observe this mistake in 8 out of 10 around me!

Answer (score 1):

Premise and premises are actually two separate words with different meanings (you didn't specify enough in your sentence to relay which way you're meaning it).

According to Google:

> premises
>
> a house or building, together with its land and outbuildings, occupied by a business or considered in an official context
>
> plural: premises

whereas

> premise
>
> a previous statement or proposition from which another is inferred or follows as a conclusion
>
> plural: premises

The word you are looking for, singular *or* plural, is `premises`.

Comment: What about the context of this question makes you believe that the first definition is the correct one? If anything, I would think that the second definition fits this phrase better... "One of the premises of this argument is...".

Comment: I didn't quite realize that, but the OP didn't specify the rest of the sentence. I made an assumption, as did the other poster. It could be "One of the premises that I lived on..." or, as you said, "One of the premises of this argument is..." No one can say which one is correct as the OP wasn't specific. Regardless, though, the answer is the same: premises.